# Throwing exception class java

Tags: java, exception, throw

I am coding a circular singly linked list

```
public class CircularSLList<T>
{

    protected class SLNode<T>
    {
        public T info = null;
        public SLNode<T> next = null;
    }

    public SLNode<T> tail = null;
    protected int size = 0;
```

I'm trying to throw a user defined exception class

```
public class EmptyListException extends RuntimeException
{
    public EmptyListException()
    {
        super();
    }
}
```

But i keep on getting an "EmptyListException can not be resolved error"

Here is my code

```
   public T removeFromHead() throws EmptyListException
    {
        if(tail == null)
        {
            throw new EmptyListException() ;
            return null ;
        }

        else
        {
            tail.next = tail.next.next ;
            tail.next.next = null ;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

All my files are in the same folder and all variable names have been spelled correctly so I cannot figure out why I'm getting this error

Thanks

Comment: Are all your files in the same package?

Comment: Please show us the project's folder structure you have, and show us from which folder you are compiling (and how). Additionally, please provide the complete source file contents (including package declaration and imports, if any).

Answer (score 0):

You have no defined package, so java won't know what to inherit from the current working directory.

Choices, specify package on the first line of each class, or manually import the required classes.